# Magento Category Flat Tables

Tags: php, magento

I have added to the category entity a lot of custom attributes, now when I try to reindex I get the error

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1118 Row size too large. The maximum row size for the used table type, not counting BLOBs, is 65535. You have to change some columns to TEXT or BLOBs
```

I Know that means that the flat tables are too large and indeed there are a lot of columns there. I don't need my custom attributes in that table so I can remove them, but how can i do that? I found that if I set the filterable and comparable to false they shouldn't be in the flat table. Any help will be appreciated

```
public function getDefaultEntities()
{
    return array(
        'catalog_category' => array(
            'entity_model'      => 'catalog/category',
            'attribute_model'   => 'catalog/resource_eav_attribute',
            'additional_attribute_table' => 'catalog/eav_attribute',
            'entity_attribute_collection' => 'catalog/category_attribute_collection',
            'table'             => 'catalog/category',
            'attributes'        => array(
                'cat_type' => array(
                    'group'             => 'General',
                    'label'             => 'Category Type',
                    'type'              => 'int',
                    'input'             => 'select',
                    'default'           => '0',
                    'class'             => '',
                    'backend'           => '',
                    'frontend'          => '',
                    'source'            => 'eav/entity_attribute_source_cattype',
                    'global'            => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_STORE,
                    'visible'           => true,
                    'required'          => false,
                    'user_defined'      => false,
                    'searchable'        => false,
                    'filterable'        => false,
                    'comparable'        => false,
                    'visible_on_front'  => false,
                    'visible_in_advanced_search' => false,
                    'unique'            => false
                ),
```

Edit:

I have deleted the attributes and it works then I ran the install script again, all of them have the filterable and comparable set to false as the example I posted below, It shows me the error again, What I'm missing?

Edit:

I checked the flat category table and I see that all the attributes are added them.
So the filterable and comparable just works for product attributes? 
I thought that they will be the same values for category products.

Is there anyway to exclude my attributes from that table?
I can exclude them modifying the file that create the table, obviously in my local folder but I want to know which is the clean way to do this?

Comment: I think you could just set *filterable* and *comparable* to FALSE for the attributes you don't require, and reindex the tables.

Comment: In the code I posted below I set those values to False, I have reindexed but I still got that problem

Answer (score 0):

Check eav_attribute table and column named used_in_product_listing set it to 0 or false and it shouldn't be added to category product flat table.